# Django apps custom folder

Tags: django-models, django-apps

I am using Django 1.10, and I created a folder called `apps`. I want to put all my apps inside this directory, but when I try to import `appA.models` inside `appB.models` I get this error.

> RuntimeError: Model class appA.models.model doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Both apps are declared in installed apps like this `apps.appA`. All folders have the init file.

Comment: Does `apps` folder have an `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was to create a folder named applications with an `__init__.py` file inside. Each app must have the file `apps.py` with this content

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
    
from django.apps import AppConfig
    
    
class AppnameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'appname'
```

Also in the in `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS`, call the applications with this format `applications.appname`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `__init__.py` named empty file first in your apps folder. Now in root `settings.py` file in `INSTALLED_APPS` add all you apps then it will work.